# Swiffy - How to use it offline

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy, fla

Hey guys is there a ways to use Google Swiffy Offline as the support will be discontinued starting of 1th July. This is a great tool and i'd like to ask if there is a way to use it offline after this date

I have Swiffy extension for Flash CS and a local version of runtime.js but when i try to use it offline to export a file from flash cs i get the following'

Swiffy Flash Extension for Win v1.1.1
The Swiffy webservice could not be reached. Please check your internet connection.

It would be appreciated if someone helps. Thanks

Comment: This is sad... They should keep swiffy converstions and just stop the service on Adwords. Swiffy is very useful for showing ads to clients in a single .html attachement with email. Now when converting with Animate in HTML5 i get great results with CreateJS but get seperated files then I have to .zip the content and send it to client. Then the client can't open html file in .zip lol.....

Answer (score 3):

Fla-Exporter does NOT compile any ActionScript, both timeline and object scripts will be excluded during the compilation, doesn't matter if it's AS1, AS2 or AS3

Unfortunately Swiffy WAS the only tool could export real HTML5/JS from -almost- any AS1/AS2 project even if that contains complex ActionScript. Furthermore, it did it with the compiled swf and didn't even need the original fla source.

My idea is that someone buys Swiffy from Google and continues to host the service with some rent model (for instance : x$/month or x$/y conversion)

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be used offline. The times they are a changing and it's sad to Swiffy go. If file size is not an issue you can use CreateJS under the Commands Menu, but you're going to need to tinker with it.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer is No. Their service is online based, even when using their flash extension.
If anyone here has tried converting Flash to Html5 with "shumway" (https://mozilla.github.io/shumway/), I'd be glad to know how is it compared to swiffy, in comments.
If somehow google's conversion engine will be released, I will update here.

Comment: Shumway is gone as well - "moved to the Firefox Graveyard". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shumway_(software)